# Time Delay in Union Operator in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am having statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM   DemoTable
WHERE i = 7
UNION
SELECT *
FROM   DemoTable
WHERE i = 6
```

What i need i need to put time delay between the union statement i need to check something related to snapshot isolation.

Can i put time delay between the union

Such as

```
SELECT *
FROM   DemoTable
WHERE i = 7
```

Will Run First and after 10 seconds

```
SELECT *
FROM   DemoTable
WHERE i = 6
```

But i need both in one statement i.e with union only.

Comment: Run two separate queries.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put a delay in the middle of the union.  A select/union is part of the SQL DML.  Delay is a programming construct and is not related to data manipulation in any way.

Also, isolation and concurrency would not be impacted by separates reads on the same table.  Reads generally use a shared lock.  You'll need to start a transaction that modifies the data in some way for there to be any impact to concurrency.  You'd be better off using multiple query windows or connections with explicit transactions.

You can use WAITFOR inside of a stored procedure, but never with a union.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.testproc
AS
BEGIN   
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02'
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
END 
go
EXEC dbo.testproc
```

Answer (score 0):

try insert `WAITFOR DELAY '00:02';`